# Set specific value to Select input on jQuery return false?

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have a Select input droplist:

```
<select class="redblue">
    <option value="Red or Blue?" selected>Red or Blue?</option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
</select>

<select class="colorslave">
    <option value="none" selected></option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
</select>
```

Everytime a color from .redblue is selected, upon confirm, .colorslave shows the same. I need .redblue to get back to default value "Red or Blue?" after confirm, be it OK or CANCEL.

Right now, it only works with OK - on CANCEL, the "return false;" must be blocking it or something:

```
$('.redblue').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'RED'){
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose RED.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('RED');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//works
        }
    }else{
        return false;
        $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//doesn't work
    }
});

$('.redblue').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'BLUE'){
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose BLUE.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('BLUE');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//works
        }
    }else{
        return false;
        $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//doesn't work
    }
});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/76f0qdqn/).

Comment: May I ask what does your confirm function returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your problem, you can see the solution [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8zjo74p/1/)

```
$('.redblue').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'RED') {
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose RED.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('RED');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
        } else {
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?'); //this code doesn't work
        }
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'BLUE') {
        var color2 = confirm("You are about to choose BLUE.");
        if (color2) {
            $('.colorslave').val('BLUE');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
        } else {
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?'); //this code doesn't work
        }
    }
});
```

Basically the problem was you needed the else statement that wasn't working under the if statement that determined whether or not the alert was an ok or a cancel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I needed! Accepted your answer, but can't +1 yet.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false immediately before the lines of code that you have marked as "doesn't work".  Of course they are not going to execute.

Furthermore, the design of your code is odd in that you are treating the color selection calls as completely separate blocks of code, when they should be a single if/else statement.  The following code <s>still does not properly reset the "redblue" drop down (I am not sure what is causing that) but</s> has better design:

```
$('.redblue').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'RED'){
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose RED.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('RED');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
        }else{
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
            return false;
        }
    }else if($(this).val() == 'BLUE'){
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose BLUE.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('BLUE');
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
        }else if (!color){
            $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

<s>This should act as a better starting point for your debugging.  I am not a jQuery master so I assume that there is something else going on from preventing a proper reset, but I think making the changes I made above should help.</s>

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I had tried both before and after return false but none worked, as you stated.

Comment: Hmm turns out that my code does actually work properly.  I retried it in the fiddle and the reset was happening as it was supposed to.  Maybe it was a page cache issue earlier.  Either way, I can see Jeremy W helped you out as well.  Glad you solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute code after you `return false`. Try inverting the two lines like this:

From:

```
return false;
$('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//doesn't work
```

To:

```
$('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');//doesn't work
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Much efficient way you can just grab the code to make it back to default outside if sentences, so it will go like this:

```
$('.redblue').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'RED') {
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose RED.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('RED');
        }
    } else if($(this).val() == 'BLUE') {
        var color = confirm("You are about to choose BLUE.");
        if (color) {
            $('.colorslave').val('BLUE');
        }
    }

    $('.redblue').val('Red or Blue?');
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76f0qdqn/4/